# Why would sshd daemon fail a connection that manually started /usr/sbin/sshd permits?

Tags: ssh, nx

The goal is to setup FreeNX. Following the advise from another [serverfault user](https://serverfault.com/questions/542305/any-reason-sshd-config-can-not-be-set-to-an-authorized-keys-file-not-in-home/542338?noredirect=1#542338) I was able to test various configurations of `ssh` and `nxsetup` connections to the sshd server as daemon or manually started instance of `/usr/sbin/sshd`.

The daemon version will not accept the connection from nxsetup but the manual instance `/usr/sbin/sshd` will.

**The steps:**

1. Start ssh-agent `eval $(ssh-agent)` and add root key `ssh-add`
2. Stop the sshd daemon,
3. Start the manual instance with:

   ```
   # /usr/sbin/sshd -d -p 22 -f /path/to/test/sshd_config_nx
   ```
4. The command I'm having trouble with is:

   ```
   # nxsetup --install --clean --purge
   ```
5. Success! *However, skip 2, 3 and connection fails*

**The setup of the sshd daemon and the manual /usr/sbin/sshd config files:**

[`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`](http://pastebin.com/0MEkqtrZ) is of course the daemon's default config directory. Both this file and my test config, `~/sshd_config_nx`, (have become) are exactly the same (diff).

**Successful ssh tests include:**

```
from client over LAN to:
    - sshd server daemon
    - manual sshd server
from ssh with loopback (127.0.0.1) to:
    - sshd server daemon
    - manual sshd server
```

**Permissions**

I read a lot of posts about ssh/sshd authentication problems involving permissions. My root user has these permissions: `/root/.ssh` is 700 and `/root/.ssh/*` is 600. The nxserver default location for authorized_keys2 is `/var/lib/nxserver/home/.ssh/`. I've applied the same permissions here. The only difference between /root and /var is the latter is owned nx:root. For this reason I tested the permissions the same for both owner and group with world still 0. This didn't make any difference, and it bugged ssh-add. So I changed them back to 700 and 600. I haven't heard that config permissions matter, but I made them both the same and since I'm performing these commands as root, the user:grooup is the same also.

Why would sshd daemon fail a connection that manually started /usr/sbin/sshd permits?

**//EDIT**: I've tried a few more things in the event I'm just stupid:

- add ssh-agent in steps.
- I made sure any changes I made to `~/.ssh` and
  `/var/lib/nxserver/home/.ssh` permissions were followed by the advise
  from another post with a similar problem with [daemon and manually
  started sshd](https://serverfault.com/questions/321534/public-key-authentication-fails-only-when-sshd-is-daemon): `#restorecon -r -vv /root/.ssh`
- The server has openssh-5.3p1-84.1.el6.i686, for this reason the authorized_key 
  file is not what you might expect. FreeNX wants authorized_keys2 located in the 
  /var directory. Its important to note here that ssh is working. The test 
  sshd_config_nx uses this /var location allways, and I toggle the line in the 
  /etc/ssh/sshd_config when I attempt the nxsetup connection through the daemon 
  (to suit the nxsetup instructions).
- added pastebin of [/etc/ssh/sshd_config](http://pastebin.com/0MEkqtrZ)
- The directories mentioned above:

  ```
  [root@mrwizard ~]# ls ~/.ssh
  drwx------.  2 root root 4096 Oct  6 17:47 .
  dr-xr-x---. 47 root root 4096 Oct  7 18:58 ..
  -rw-------.  1 root root 2761 Oct  5 18:50 authorized_keys
  -rw-------.  1 root root 1865 Oct  6 15:54 authorized_keys2
  -rw-------.  1 root root 1679 Oct  6 15:52 authorized_keys2.new
  -rw-------.  1 root root 1743 Oct  5 18:38 id_rsa
  -rw-------.  1 root root  401 Oct  5 18:38 id_rsa.pub
  -rw-------.  1 root root  391 Oct  6 17:47 known_hosts 

  [root@mrwizard ~]# ls -al /var/lib/nxserver/home/.ssh/
  drwx------. 2 nx root 4096 Oct 7 18:38 . 
  drwx------. 5 nx root 4096 Oct  7 18:38 ..
  -rw-------. 1 nx root  669 Oct  7 18:38 authorized_keys2
  -rw-------. 1 nx root  668 Oct  7 18:38 client.id_dsa.key
  -rw-r--r--. 1 nx root  392 Oct  7 18:38 known_hosts 

  [root@mrwizard ~]# ls -al /etc/ssh/
  drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root   4096 Oct  6 18:47 . 
  drwxr-xr-x. 135 root root  12288 Oct  7 18:38 ..
  -rw-------.   1 root root 125811 Feb 21  2013 moduli
  -rw-r--r--.   1 root root   2061 Sep 22 14:32 ssh_config
  -rw-------.   1 root root   4492 Oct  6 18:47 sshd_config
  -rw-------.   1 root root    668 Oct  5 16:53 ssh_host_dsa_key
  -rw-r--r--.   1 root root    590 Oct  5 16:53 ssh_host_dsa_key.pub
  -rw-------.   1 root root    963 Oct  5 16:53 ssh_host_key
  -rw-r--r--.   1 root root    627 Oct  5 16:53 ssh_host_key.pub
  -rw-------.   1 root root   1671 Oct  5 16:53 ssh_host_rsa_key
  -rw-r--r--.   1 root root    382 Oct  5 16:53 ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `selinux` enabled.  For failed connections you should see entries in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`.  You have two options:

- Disable `selinux`.  Go ahead, all your friends are doing it.
- Fix your `selinux` configuration.  This may be as simple as running `fixfiles` with the appropriate arguments to relabel your filesystem, or it may require explicitly setting the `selinux` context of files or directories.

If you opt for the second -- arguably more correct but more labor intensive -- solution, you may want to open a second question containing the relevant entries from your `audit.log`.

You can try out the first solution by running:

```
# setenforce 0
```

This will put `selinux` into permissive mode, but is not persistent across a reboot.  To persistently disable `selinux`, edit `/etc/selinux/config` and set:

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

Or:

```
SELINUX=permissive
```

The latter setting will leave `selinux` enabled but in permissive mode, so it will log violations to `audit.log` but will not

Comment: Thanks. This helped me to find [install FreeNX with SELinux](http://www.unixmen.com/install-and-configure-freenx-server/)